# Unity references break after scene reload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a weird issue in unity, the references keep breaking as soon as i reload a scene, i tried to understand what is really going on but no luck.
i made a script to replicate the issue you can find bellow.

when i edit the last data element "list" by changing the size, the change is reflected on the other data objects list, cause they are treated just as references.
[image].

if i reload the scene, the changes are not reflected anymore as previously, it behaves like copies instead of references this time.
can someone help me figure out what is going on ?
[image].

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{

    public List<data> Data = new List<data>();
}
[System.Serializable]
public class data
{

    public List<int> list = new List<int>();
}
[CustomEditor(typeof(test))]
public class testEditor:Editor
{
    test test;
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        test = (test)target;
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            data data = new data();
            if (test.Data.Count >= 1) data.list = test.Data[test.Data.Count - 1].list;
            test.Data.Add(data);

            EditorUtility.SetDirty(test);
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Clear"))
        {
            test.Data.Clear();

            EditorUtility.SetDirty(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding ```DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);``` in your Start of Awake function

Comment: Hi, this is an editor plugin question, i have found the issue, i mentioned it in a comment bellow
thanx

Answer (score 2):

In general: Don't directly access and change the values of your `MonoBehaviour` instance!

As you noted you will have to handle all kind of marking dirty and saving yourself. What you experience when re-opening the scene in the Editor that something wasn't marked dirty correctly and thus not saved together with the scene.

---

Always rather go through [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html)s which handle all the marking dirty and saving and especially also undo/redo etc. automatically:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(test))]
public class testEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty Data;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        Data = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(test.Data));
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        // load all current values of the properties in test into the SerializedProperty "clones"
        serializedObject.Update();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            // this simply adds a new entry to the list
            // since the data and list are both serializable this already initializes them with values
            Data.arraySize++;


            // Actually the entire following block is redundant 
            // by using Data.arraySize++; the new added entry automatically 
            // is a full copy of the entry before!
            // I just decided to add it as example how you would access further nested SerializedProperties

            //// if there was an element before now there are two
            //if (Data.arraySize >= 2)
            //{
            //    // get the last added element
            //    var lastElement = Data.GetArrayElementAtIndex(Data.arraySize - 1);
            //    var beforeElement = Data.GetArrayElementAtIndex(Data.arraySize - 2);

            //    // deep clone the list
            //    var lastElementList = lastElement.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(data.list));
            //    var beforeElementList = beforeElement.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(data.list));

            //    lastElementList.arraySize = beforeElementList.arraySize;
            //    for (var i = 0; i < lastElementList.arraySize; i++)
            //    {
            //        lastElementList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).intValue = beforeElementList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).intValue;
            //    }
            //}
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Clear"))
        {
            Data.arraySize = 0;
        }

        // write back the values of the SerializedProperty "clones" into the real properties of test
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

This now handles all marking dirty, saving the scene correctly, undo/redo etc automatically and you don't have to take care about that anymore.

---

And then a little "pro" tip: Use [`ReorderableList`](https://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist)! It looks a bit tricky to set up but is extremly powerful: Among other things as the name says it allows you to simply reorder the elements by drag and drop in the Inspector and also allows to delete an item from the middle which is impossible with the normal list drawer. This completely replaces your `Add` and `Clear` buttons:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;

[CustomEditor(typeof(test))]
public class testEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty Data;
    private ReorderableList dataList;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        Data = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(test.Data));

        //                                 should the list
        //                                                     | be reorderable by drag&drop of the entries?
        //                                                     |     | display a header for the list?
        //                                                     |     |     | have an Add button?
        //                                                     |     |     |     | have a Remove button?
        //                                                     v     v     v     v
        dataList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, Data, true, true, true, true)
        {
            // what shall be displayed as header
            drawHeaderCallback = rect => EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, Data.displayName),

            elementHeightCallback = index =>
            {
                var element = Data.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
                var elementList = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(data.list));
                return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * (elementList.isExpanded ? elementList.arraySize + 4 : 3);
            },

            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, isFocused, isActive) =>
            {
                var element = Data.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), element.displayName);
                // in order to print the list in the next line
                rect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                var elementList = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(data.list));
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width,  EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * (elementList.isExpanded ? elementList.arraySize + 1 : 1)), elementList, true);
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // load all current values of the properties in test into the SerializedProperty "clones"
        serializedObject.Update();

        dataList.DoLayoutList();

        // write back the values of the SerializedProperty "clones" into the real properties of test
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Note** If not the case already anyway: 
The `testEditor` part should

- either be placed in a different script in a folder called `Editor`
- or you should wrap anything related to the `UnityEditor` namespace within pre-processors like

  ```
  #if UNITY_EDITOR
  using UnityEditor;
  using UnityEditorInternal;
  #endif

  ...

  #if UNITY_EDITOR
  [CustomEditor(typeof(test))]
  public class testEditor : Editor
  {
      ...
  }
  #endif
  ```

otherwise you will get errors when building the app since the `UnityEditor` namespace is stripped of in a build and exists only inside the Unity Editor itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time, and for the advice of using reorderable list and serialized properties, in fact i use them all the time but in the example that i have put above, i just wanted to replicate the issue , and it seams like i found what's this was all about, the code that i have written above is correct, it seams like the issue is that Unity does not serialize custom classes as mentioned in the doc [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html), when unity do deserialization it creates copies of the class object instead of linking references back again,

Comment: @BadrDouah no as said the serialization works since you can see the class in the inspector ... what does not work is something in your script about marking stuff as dirty and thus it is not saved correctly into the scene but rather remains a temporary value until you re-open the scene. Therefore as said: Don't directly write the values but rather use SerializedProperty that is the correct way of writing Editor scripts

Comment: Hi , did you read this part of the unity docs link i posted above. 

"With custom classes that are not derived from UnityEngine.Object Unity serializes them inline by value, similar to the way it serializes structs. If you store a reference to an instance of a custom class in several different fields, they become separate objects when serialized. Then, when Unity deserializes the fields, they contain different distinct objects with identical data."